# how to limit the network bandwidth in kafka cluster by kafka-mm2

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to find the config that limit the data's speed to copy in kafka cluster by mm2, but mm2 is not seemed to supply such config. For example, the system's bandwidth is 100M/s, but I want to set it 5M/s in clusters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to identify the mm2 user with authentication, you can use [Kafka quotas](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_quotas)

> Two types of client quotas can be enforced by Kafka brokers for each group of clients sharing a quota:
>
> 1. Network bandwidth quotas define byte-rate thresholds (since 0.9)
> 2. Request rate quotas define CPU utilization thresholds as a percentage of network and I/O threads (since 0.11)